# How to pass source and destination path in NSTask arguments for LZip?

Tags: objective-c, macos, compression, nstask, lzip

I am trying to Unarchive the Lzip file so using NSTask to achieve it 
`[task setArguments:@[@"-k",@"-d",source,destination]];` these are the arguments which i was passing but extraction always happens in source path folder .

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

After some Research i come up with the solution

`[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-k",@"-d", source,@"-O", destination, nil]];`

`-k` keep (don't delete) input files.

`-d` decompress.

`-O` if reading standard input, write to file.